# Expanding array inside For Loop conditional isn't being iterated on until the end of the array

Tags: groovy, jira

Here is a rough but working approximation of my code

```
ArrayList<Integer> parents = new ArrayList<Integer>([1, 2, 8, 9])

def p = parents as Queue

p.find {
    log.info("it is " + it)
    if (it == 5) return true
    p += 5
    log.info("p is " + p)
    return false
}

log.info("finally, p is " + p)
```

Here is the Log

```
2020-01-09 16:35:55,971 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: it is 1
2020-01-09 16:35:55,971 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: p is [1, 2, 8, 9, 5]
2020-01-09 16:35:55,971 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: it is 2
2020-01-09 16:35:55,972 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: p is [1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 5]
2020-01-09 16:35:55,972 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: it is 8
2020-01-09 16:35:55,972 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: p is [1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 5, 5]
2020-01-09 16:35:55,972 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: it is 9
2020-01-09 16:35:55,972 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: p is [1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5]
2020-01-09 16:35:55,972 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: finally, p is [1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

The loop should have iterated on 5 once, but it does not, why is that? `p` is having 5 added to it, and the log shows this which means the array is expanding but the loop only runs 4 times, which is the size of the original array.

The same thing is happening in my actual code where I am searching an array's items using a `for (i in p)` to find i's parent values (folder in directory structure), and then adding those results to p so I can keep going up the directory structure until no more parents are found.

Environment:
Groovy script running in Jira via Script Runner.

Comment: you should NOT find and update in the same time

Comment: i don't know your goal, but according to your algorithm - you are adding element `5` for each `non-5` element into your array unless you met `5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are adding elements to the same collection you are iterating over. In many cases Groovy will actually give you a `ConcurrentModificationException` at runtime. To solve this you can iterate using indices instead of an iterator. Information I got from [this site](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-To-Avoid-And-Resolve-ConcurrentModificationException-in-Java-And-Groovy/)

```
ArrayList<Integer> parents = new ArrayList<Integer>([1, 2, 8, 9])

def p = parents as Queue

for(int i=0; i<p.size(); i++) {
    log.info("it is " + p[i])
    if (p[i] == 5) break
    p += 5
    log.info("p is " + p)
}

log.info("finally, p is " + p)
```

Which produces the following output:

```
2020-01-10 11:35:05,468 DEBUG [runner.WithPluginCompilationCustomiser]: Compile Script2754.groovy, to node: Script2754
2020-01-10 11:35:06,414 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: it is 1
2020-01-10 11:35:06,414 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: p is [1, 2, 8, 9, 5]
2020-01-10 11:35:06,414 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: it is 2
2020-01-10 11:35:06,414 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: p is [1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 5]
2020-01-10 11:35:06,414 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: it is 8
2020-01-10 11:35:06,414 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: p is [1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 5, 5]
2020-01-10 11:35:06,414 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: it is 9
2020-01-10 11:35:06,414 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: p is [1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5]
2020-01-10 11:35:06,414 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: it is 5
2020-01-10 11:35:06,414 INFO [runner.AbstractScriptRunner]: finally, p is [1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```